# HTML5 Local Storage with saved integers and variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm trying to achieve a function that makes the user able to save a mathematical formula that uses static variables that I've already created and save them with Local Storage.
Then the script fetches that formula from the Local Storage, does the math and displays the results on a table.

I have everything in order, except the fetching part;
as localStorage.getItem() returns a string, and converting it with parseFloat()/parseInt() only returns the first integer or NaN.
Both of this messes up the expected the results.

Is there any way I can get Objects from localStoage that contains both integers and variables?

Heres an example of a formula that should work, fetched by 5 localStorage.getItem() requests.

```
avgFrags*250
avgDmg*(10/(avgTier+2))*(0.23+2*avgTier/100)
avgSpots*150
log(avgCap+1,1.732)*150
avgDef*150
```

Any ideas or alternatives?

EDIT:

Each line represents the output of a getItem() request;

```
form_frag = localStorage.getItem('formula_frag');
form_dmg = localStorage.getItem('formula_dmg');
form_spot = localStorage.getItem('formula_spot');
form_cap = localStorage.getItem('formula_cap');
form_def = localStorage.getItem('formula_def');
```

Answer (score 3):

localStorage store in a key-value store where every value is pushed to a string. If you are certent that you are handling "integers" you can push the string to a number:

```
var avgFrags = +localStorage.getItem('avgFrags'); // The + infront pushes the string to number.
```

I'm not completely sure that I understand your question.

```
(+"123") === 123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert easily convert your strings to functions if you know the variable names before hand using `Function()`.  The first parameter(s) are your function arguments and the last is your function body.

```
var func1 = Function('avgFrags', 'return avgFrags * 250;');
```

This is equivalent to:

```
function func1(avgFrags) {
    return avgFrags * 250;
}
```

**Known Function Signature**

If you know what variable names will be used for each item in local storage then it should be easy for you to do what you want with function:

```
// from your edited question
form_frag = localStorage.getItem('formula_frag');
form_dmg = localStorage.getItem('formula_dmg');

// ... create functions

var fragsFunc = Function('avgFrags', form_frg );
var dmgFunc = Function('avgDmg', 'avgTier', form_dmg );

// ... get frags

var frags = fragsFunc (10); // frags = 2500; // if sample in storage
```

**Unknown Function Signature**

Now if you have a limited amount of variable names and you don't know which ones will be used with each function then you can do something like:

```
var avgFrags, avgDamage, avgTier, avgSpots, avgCap, avgDef;

// ... get from storage

form_frag = localStorage.getItem('formula_frag');
form_dmg = localStorage.getItem('formula_dmg');

// ... create functions

var fragsFunc = Function('avgFrags', 'avgDamage', 'avgTier', 'avgSpots', 'avgCap', 'avgDef', form_frag);
var dmgFunc = Function('avgFrags', 'avgDamage', 'avgTier', 'avgSpots', 'avgCap', 'avgDef', form_frag);

// ... get frags, only the first argument is used, but we don't know that.

var frags = fragsFunc (avgFrags, avgDamage, avgTier, avgSpots, avgCap, avgDef); // frags = 2500; // if sample in storage
```

You can make this simpler by having just one variable passed into the function which is an object that holds all of the arguments that can be passed to the function.  Just have to make sure that the function writer uses that object.

```
var settings = { 
    avgFrags: 10, 
    avgDamage: 50,
    // ...
};

var fragsFunc = Function('s', 's.avgFrags * 250');

var frags = fragsFunc (settings);
```

**Getting parts with an regex**

I am assuming that the above will get the job done, that you don't *really* want an object with variable names and numbers and operators.

If you just need the variable names and numbers (and operators) you can use a regex for that.

```
([a-z_$][\w\d]*)|([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)|([^\w\d\s])
```

You can use that to create an array with each part.  Also each part is grouped so you know which is a variable name, which is a number, and which is an other (parenthesis or operator)

```
var re = /(\w[\w\d]*)|([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)|([^\w\d\s])/g,
    match,
    results;

while ((match = re.exec(localStorage.getItem('formula_frag'))) {
    results.push({
        text: match[0],
        type: (match[1]) ? 'var' | (match[2]) ? 'number' : 'other'
    })
}
```

You can view the output of the regex with your sample data using **[REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/jk8qfvg2)**.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I'll see if I can make use of this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set Objects in localstorage

Here is the fiddle for that - http://jsfiddle.net/sahilbatla/2z0dq6o3/

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
}

$(function() {
    localStorage.setObject('x', {1: 2, 2: "s"})
    console.log(localStorage.getObject('x'));
});
```